# ApplicationRoleManager - dose not have any type parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity

My application role class

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }

    public ApplicationRole()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationRole(string roleName) : base(roleName) { }

    public ApplicationRole(string roleName, string roleDescription) : base(roleName)
    {
        Description = roleDescription;
    }

}
```

My Application Role Manager class

```
    public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
        {
            public ApplicationRoleManager(ApplicationRoleStore roleStore, 
            IEnumerable<IRoleValidator<ApplicationRole>> roleValidators,
            ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer, 
            IdentityErrorDescriber errors, 
            ILogger<ApplicationRoleManager> logger) :
            base(roleStore , roleValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, logger)
            {
            }
        }
```

My Application Role Store class

```
   public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public ApplicationRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext dbContext, 
        IdentityErrorDescriber identityErrorDescriber) :
        base(dbContext, identityErrorDescriber)
        {

        }
    }
```

And ApplicationDbContext

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor,IConfiguration configuration)
            : base(dbContextOptions)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

When i write this Give me an error :

```
  private readonly ApplicationRoleManager<ApplicationRole>  _roleManager;
```

> Class ApplicationRoleManager dose not have type parameters

I cant understand Where is my fault.

Comment: Is this in ASP.NET Core identity? Everything looks like alien to me! May be this is not the proper way to use `IdenityRole` in asp.net core. There is much simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, class `ApplicationRoleManager` does not have type parameters.

Change:

```
private readonly ApplicationRoleManager<ApplicationRole>  _roleManager;
```

To:

```
private readonly ApplicationRoleManager  _roleManager;
```

[More about type parameters here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters)